# Ignore character which is not supporting in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, xmlpullparser

How to Ignore **'&'** charterer while reading XML file. 
what I want is, First I read xml file and then Print Content to list view.. but in some case my content contain some special charecter Like

> & ,' , "

etc..

how can I ignore?
this is my code for read xml from sdcard.

**MainActivity**

```
 XmlPullHandler parser = new XmlPullHandler();
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/myfile.xml");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

**PullHendler class**

```
 XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

            XmlPullParser  parser = factory.newPullParser();

             parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

**OR** Is this Possible to replace character while reading file.. **(i.e. & is replaced by &amp)**

this is **Myfile.Xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <MyLine>   
<Line>Live your life sharing the Beauty & Happiness, that you have today.
</Line> 
</MyLine>
```

this is my **pullHandlerclass**

```
 int eventType = parser.getEventType();
      while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    String tagname = parser.getName();
                    switch (eventType) {
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Line")) {

                                line = new Lines();
                            }
                            break;

                        case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                            text = parser.getText();
                            break;

                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Line")) {
                                lines.add(line);
                                lines.setLine(text);
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    eventType = parser.next();
                }

            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return lines;
        }
```

Comment: Why you want to ignore them what is the problem ?? and where the code which fetches **String** data from file??

Comment: the problem is it gives unsupportedformatexeption. i tried to handle it but not working.. becoz xml file not supported this format

Comment: Show a bit of your XML file where you get the exception

Comment: Share the full code and tell me on which line the exception is coming..!!

Comment: Why are you setting the input twice? Show me how you've using the parser after setting input.

Comment: @jankigadhiya http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112107/android-smartness

Comment: @janki http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112107/android-smartness

Comment: @janki Check my answer below. I hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this. Add replacements for other HTML entities after `line = line.replaceAll("&", "&amp;")`

```
String fileData = "";
String line = "";

BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    line = line.replace("&", "&amp;");
    fileData += line;
    fileData += "\n";
}

parser.setInput(new StringReader(fileData));
```

This is not efficient though as memory goes because it will load the entire XML file into a string. I'd be able to provide a better solution if you show what you're doing with your XML parser.